# How to perform a event of XML which is created for Listview separately

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm displaying my contacts in one listview by using Sqlite.I designed the XML layout for the listview separately. I used that XML in the adapter class by using layout inflator. Now I want to perform events for the views which are in designed XML. How can I get those views to perform events.

**`Adapter Class Code:`**

```
 public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
   View listItem;
    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listItem=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_design,parent,false);

    contacts=new ArrayList<>();
    final ContactsModel contact = contacts.get(position);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.photo_iv);
    image.setImageBitmap(contact.getImage());


    TextView name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
    name.setText(contact.getName());

    TextView number = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.number_tv);
    number.setText(contact.getNumber());

    ImageView img=(ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.edit_iv);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db=new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
           int id= contact.getId();
           ContactsModel contact = db.getContact(id);

        }
    });

    return listItem;
}
```

Observe the below image for my listview, separate XML design which is used for kist view and images to perform events

[image]

Please Help me.

**`getContact()` Method Code :**

```
 public ContactsModel getContact(long id){
    ContactsModel c=new ContactsModel();
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(c.Table_Name,new String[]{c.ColumnContactName,c.ColumnNumber,c.ColumnPhoto},c.Columnid +"=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.ColumnPhoto)), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    ContactsModel model=new ContactsModel(
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.ColumnContactName)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.ColumnNumber)),bitmap);

    cursor.close();
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter code?

Comment: @TakeInfos, I added code, please check once

Comment: @Priyanka can you share XML design?

Comment: @Priyanka I have added code check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give `id` to those two icons in xml file.

Then get those two icons by id in `adapter class`.

set on click listener on those two icons and perform action whatever you want.

```html
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
   View listItem;
    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listItem=inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_design,parent,false);

    ContactsModel contact = contacts.get(position);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.photo_iv);
    image.setImageBitmap(contact.getImage());
    
    //Give icons a id in xml file and get those view in adapter class and set onclick listener to perform event.
   
    ImageView icon_one = (ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.icon_one);
        ImageView icon_two = (ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.icon_two);
    
    icon_one.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              ***Do what you want with the click here***
            }
        });
        icon_two.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              ***Do what you want with the click here***
            }
        });

    TextView name = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
    name.setText(contact.getName());
    
    TextView number = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.number_tv);
    number.setText(contact.getNumber());

    return listItem;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198542/discussion-on-answer-by-take-infos-how-to-perform-a-event-of-xml-which-is-create).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the code bellow:

```
class ContactAdapter(
    private val onClickListener: OnClickListener
) : ListAdapter<ContactsModel, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        listItem.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListener.onClick(item)
        }
    }


    class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (item: ContactsModel) -> Unit) {
        fun onClick(item: ContactsModel) = clickListener(item)
    }

}
```